# Logistic regression giving negative predictions?

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I am doing a binomial-family logistic regression, but my predictions on the datasets are almost all negative. Is this because the resulting predictions are actually log-likelihoods, not pure probability estimates? And could someone point me to a good resource to learn more about how logistic regressions are determined?

Comment: Sounds unlikely... Are you sure that you are talking about estimated probabilities and not the regression coefficients?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I used predict() function in R to get the values after the logistic regression (glm, family=binomial) was computed, and most of the values came out negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is probably on a logit scale. Try to add
 `type="response"' to the` predict function. I.e., 
'
predict(your.model, new.data, type="response")
'